# Finding the correct $x$ to $ax - by = 1$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, gcd-and-lcm, euclidean-algorithm

I want to find the modular inverse of $5 \pmod {13}$ such that :
$$ 5x - 13y = 1$$

I tried to use the Euclidean alogritm for the GCD and use the extension(Extended Euclidean Algorithm) to solve for x.
Looks like this:
\begin{align}
13 &= 5(2) + 3\\
5 &= 3(1) + 2\\
3 &= 2(1) + 1
\end{align}

Then the extended:

\begin{align}
1 &= 3 - 2(1)\\
&= 3 - 1(5 - 3(1))\\
&= 3(2) - 5\\
&= 2(13 - 5(2)) - 5\\
&= 2(13) - 5(4) - 5\\
&= 13(2) - 5(5)\\
\end{align}

After that , I found that something in my solution is wrong but I can't point where it is. Because I tried to substitute for $x$ with 5.

$$
5(5) - 13(2) = -1
$$

It resulted $-1$ instead of $1.$

Note : I want $x$ to be a positive integer to make it applicable.

Comment: You could just do $$5(-5)+13(2)=1$$

Comment: $-5\equiv8 \mod 13$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You proved correctly that$$13\times2-5\times5=1$$and this is the same thing as asserting that$$5\times(-5)-13\times(-2)=1.$$So, the inverse of $5$ modulo $13$ is $-5(=8)$.